Error installing the Python library undetected-chromedriver
I decided to try parsing the OZON marketing plugin, for this you need Python library undetected-chromedriver. But when entering a query - "pip install undetected-chromedriver", the following error occurs:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting undetected-chromedriver     
    Using cached undetected-chromedriver-3.5.5.tar.gz (65 kB)     
    Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error      
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error    

    × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [43 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
          File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dn9by6m0\undetected-chromedriver_20cb32eae0cb41a5a84a593f42c4e6fc\setup.py", line 39, in <module>
            setup(
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py", line 117, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line 145, in setup
            _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 283, in __init__
            _Distribution.init(self, dist_attrs)
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 279, in __init__
            self.finalize_options()
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 634, in finalize_options
            for ep in sorted(loaded, key=by_order):
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 633, in <lambda>
            loaded = map(lambda e: e.load(), filtered)
                                   ^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\metadata_init.py", line 205, in load
            module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib_init.py", line 90, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\cx_Freeze_init.py", line 11, in <module>
            from .command.build_exe import BuildEXE as build_exe
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\cx_Freeze\command\build_exe.py", line 14, in <module>
            from cx_Freeze.freezer import Freezer
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 31, in <module>
            from .finder import ModuleFinder
          File "C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 33, in <module>
            IMPORT_STAR = opcode.opmap["IMPORT_STAR"]
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        KeyError: 'IMPORT_STAR'
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata. 
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip. 
hint: See above for details.

I tried to change the pip version.
Please help to solve this problem.

Looks like Python version problem.

So what do I do?

Google is your best friend in this scenario. Or you need to include your Python version and steps to reproduce the same error.

Pypi lists compatibility up to python 3.11, so try that python version instead

Information about this package on PyPi shows that it supports Python 3.7 - 3.11.
You may want to downgrade your Python from 3.12 to 3.10 or 3.11 and try again.
